# How to select a column normally alongside DISTINCT columns?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, age, city FROM People;
```

There is also a column called 'Description' which I would like to also return, how do I add this to the query without it trying to select distinct on that column as well?

I'm using Access 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose one value, such as the `min()` or `max()` and use `group by`:

```
SELECT name, age, city, MIN(description)
FROM People
GROUP BY name, age, city;
```